# Meteor ES6 modules relative paths

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Just came back to meteor, and trying to figure out how to structure a project, I'm getting stuck with how to handle relative paths, my project structure is like this:

```
-root
--client
----components
-----layout
...... MainLayout.jsx
--server
--lib
.. routes.jsx
```

If I try to import in my routes.jsx file like this './../client/components/layout/MainLayout.jsx' I get the error 'Cannot find module './../client/components/layout/MainLayout.jsx...

However if I move MainLayout.jsx to the root folder, i can reach the component file like this without problems './../MainLayout.jsx'.

Maybe I'm missing something here? as I said just returned to JS programming.

Answer (score 0):

When the router.js file in the root. You have use instead of

> './../client/components/layout/MainLayout.jsx'

this:

> '../client/components/layout/MainLayout.jsx'

or just:

> '../client/components/layout/MainLayout'